# Create a logbook wrapper

Tags: python, logbook

i'm new to logging and python and have found a library called `logbook` that i would like to use. i'm trying some kind of wrapper that `intiliaze` the log file and i then can call it from different files.

but i keep getting below error. What am i doing wrong?

```
self.stream = io.open(self._filename, mode, encoding=self.encoding)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```

**logger.py**

```
from logbook import Logger, StreamHandler
from logbook import FileHandler
import sys
import os

log = Logger()

initialized = False

def make_log_dir_if_missing(log_dir):
    import cheetax.utils.system
    cheetax.system.make_directory(log_dir)

def initialize_logger(path=None):
    global initialized, log

    if initialized:
        return

    if path is not None:
        make_log_dir_if_missing(path)
        log_path = os.path.join(path, 'logger.log')

    log_handler = FileHandler(path)
    log_handler.push_application()


    initialized = True


GLOBAL_LOGGER = log
```

**cli.py**

```
def main():
    initialize_logger()
```

**other files**

```
logger.info(welcome)
```

Comment: Any reason you're not using the standard Python [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) library?

Comment: not really if u can provide any minimal solution like above im open for it

Comment: Here is a quick example that writes to a file. https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#logging-to-a-file

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are not providing a default logging directory, so the line `log_handler = FileHandler(path)` will fail when you don't pass anything to `initialize_logger()`. Simply add and else to the `if path is None` statement that sets `path` to some location :)

---

Even better, simply change `path=None` to `path='/path/to/default.log'` or something.